# Could not load file or assembly c#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-assembly

On my computer I do not get this error but when I give my program to anyone else and they try to log in they get that error and the DLL is MySQL.Data.DLL.  I was wondering how I can load/add this assembly without any external files like everything is in the program I have looked all over the internet but could not find a solution.

Comment: When you ask a question like this, you need to include the *exact* error message.  And welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @John what do you mean by "give my program"? Do you give the source code or compiled binary?

Comment: @MadSorcerer When i mean by "give" i meant like i gave the release build the exe file.

Answer (score 0):

The person you give the program to would have to have MySQL installed on their machine. That way, the solution can browse to the appropriate directory of the DLL and reference it.

If you really don't want them to install the driver (someone should verify this for me);

1. Take the DLL from your directory, and put it in a common folder in
   the solution
2. Remove the existing reference, and add the reference to
   the DLL in the new common folder you created

Comment: But it does not make sense that they would have to download it like is their anyway of using the dll in the Solution Explorer and then the program can just read the dll from there?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Nuget, this is a package manager.

To get Nuget go to "Tools" in Visual Studio menu, then "Extensions and Updates"

Search for Nuget and install it

[image: get Nuget packages manager]

On your project, right click and choose "Manage Nuget Packages" then search for MySql.

[image: right click on solution]

The first answer is the right one, click Install.

[image: Nuget package manager]

Done !

Comment: wouldn't the user still need MySQL driver installed, or does this do the installing?

Comment: Can you send me a link to nuget cause when i looked it up on google and downloaded it, nothing happened

Comment: @John the first picture shows how to use Nuget in Visual Studio. Are you using Visual Studio to develop your application?

Comment: to get nuget you can go to Tools menu in Visual Studio then Extensions and Update

Comment: @failedprogramming Yes i am using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express

Comment: @AurelienSouchet When i right click it still does not show Manage NuGet Packages, and i did install it

Comment: must be because you use 2010, you can either download 2013 express, or go to Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console, at the bottom of VS a prompt appear, type this command "Install-Package MySql.Data"

Comment: Make sure you right-click on the project or on the references folder and not on a .cs file.

Comment: @AurelienSouchet will i be able to open my project even though it was made in 2010 express?

Comment: When you open a solution with a newer VS version than the one you create the project on, it will automatically update it, most of the time it works fine, but depends what is your project, if it's a library or wpf application the it's fine i guess, very old things like classic asp things like that maybe some things are not compatible with 2013. best way to find out try to download it, or 2012 express is fine too, and it's free so the worst that can happen is you uninstall it just after.

Comment: @AurelienSouchet i figured out the problem they need mysql net connector for the program to work is there any way of putting that installer in my program so it installs it for them? or can i install the dll in the directory?